# Getting wrong headers for Traefik ForwardAuth middleware

Tags: python, django, middleware, traefik, traefik-ingress

I've been trying to develop a custom auth thing for Traefik using Django and the [ForwardAuth middleware](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/forwardauth/). Unfortunately, I'm having troubles with the provided headers for my application:

- My auth app has three endpoints:

  - `/auth/`, which checks whether the user is authenticated. If it is, returns a "OK" with status code 200. If it's not, tries to get the `X-Forwarded-Host` in order to build a redirect argument using `f"?redirect={request.headers['X-Forwarded-Proto']}://{request.headers['X-Forwarded-Host']}"` and then redirect to `/auth/login/{redirect_url}`
  - `/auth/login`, which renders a form and then authenticates with Django (it uses the same logic as `/auth/` for setting up a redirect URL
  - `/auth/logout`
- It's exposed at `https://auth.my-ip.nip.io`, using the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: django-auth
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`auth.my-ip.nip.io`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: django-auth
          port: 80
  tls:
    secretName: auth.my-ip.nip.io
```

- The middleware is configured as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: django-auth
spec:
  forwardAuth:
    address: https://auth.my-ip.nip.io:443/auth/
    trustForwardHeader: true
```

- Finally, I've got an example app exposed and using the `django-auth` middleware:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: game-2048
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`2048.my-ip.nip.io`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: game-2048
          port: 80
      middlewares:
        - name: django-auth
  tls:
    secretName: 2048.my-ip.nip.io
```

But then, when I try to access `https://2048.my-ip.nip.io`, I'm getting the following headers on my `/auth/` Django view:

```py
{
  ...
  'X-Forwarded-Host': 'auth.my-ip.nip.io:443',
  'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https',
  ...
}
```

which then forces my app to identify `https://auth.my-ip.nip.io` as the redirect URL, while it should be `https://2048.my-ip.nip.io` so I could return to my example app.

I'd be glad if you could help me, I'm probably missing something. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Traefik is deployed using Helm with default values, version is 2.5.4.